# Resolving VirtualBox's DNS through proxy server

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, dns, proxy

My host is OSX and VirtualBox guest is Linux. I enter a socks5 proxy in proxifier and check "Resolve hostnames through proxy". In Safari both my IP address and DNS is changed to whatever remote proxy server have but in VirtualBox when i open any browser, the IP address is changed but my own DNS is leaked. For example if proxy server is located in UK and I'm from Germany, IP address show as UK but DNS show as Germany.

How do i resolve DNS lookups in VirtualBox through proxy server?

Comment: Could you clarify one thing?  Did you also enter the socks5 proxy in proxifier on the guest, or are you expecting the host's proxifier to do this for you? And, BTW, are you using a NAT or a bridge  adapter?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the guest Linux doesn't support installing proxifier so I can use proxy only at host. it is NAT, i tried bridge adapter but in that mode even the IP address is leaked!

Comment: @MariusMatutiae another VM have Host-only adapter, i think both NAT and Host-only adapter use same route